# setting header in php for offline client

Tags: php, cordova

Am making a phonegap application and as per personal understanding, the only languages available are CSS,HTML and Javascript.

Currently wanted to ask that since the app will be offline (i.e. not hosted on any web server). how can the php header be set to accept  cross domain calls to send JSON.

```
 used the following code

 if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
    {
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    }
```

the header is only set if a call is received from a web server (i.e. HTTP_ORIGIN is set). but as said that the phonegap app will work offline so no `HTTP_ORIGIN` may be set. and have read that php does not allow the following:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'");
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: If it's offline how will you be sending JSON?

Comment: @tlenss apologies for my mixing up terms, by offline I mean that phonegap will not send any `HTTP_ORIGIN` (or will it ? )

Answer (score 0):

You do not need special headers in your php pages, you can configure phonegap to access either specific servers or any servers :

In www/config.xml, replace the line

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
```

with

```
<access origin="*" />
```

or

```
<access origin="http://whateverserverip*" />
```

Comment: thank you for answer. will let know. but can these be set when building through Phonegap build service

Comment: config.xml is the configuration file also for phonegap build. In cli it's www/config.xml, with phonegapbuild it's config.xml at the root of your zip (or can also be www/config.xml in the zip sent to phonegap build).